# Javascript is not running in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

can someone be happy to help me, in my code below I'm trying to display a div with a dropdown select, but why is the existing javascript not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #business {
  display: none;
}
#local {
  display: none;
}

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#purpose').on('change', function () {
                if (this.value === "1") {
                    $("#business").show();
                    $("#local").hide();
                } else if (this.value === "2") {
                    $("#business").hide();
                    $("#local").show();
                } else {
                    $("#business").hide();
                    $("#local").hide();
                }
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id='purpose'>
        <option value="0">Personal use</option>
        <option value="1">Business use</option>
        <option value="2">Passing on to a client</option>
    </select>
    <div id="business">
        <label for="business">Business Name</label>
        <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
    </div>
    <div id="local">
        <label for="local">Local Name</label>
        <input type='text' class='text' name='local' value size='20' />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code works fine if i run it in fiddle, but not when i run it on my local computer, can someone help me, what should i do for the above problem, any kind of help i thank you.

Comment: A div inside a drop-down actually isn't possible....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript is not working in HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818577/javascript-is-not-working-in-html-file)

Answer (score 0):

The `<select id='purpose'>` doesn't exist yet when you try to run `$('#purpose').on('change', ...)`. Either move your `<script>` tag to the end of the `<body>` tag, or add a `defer` attribute to the tag (which follows  [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup) anyways).

Comment: @superStromer thanks for the helpm, i tried it and it works now. thank you .